# Neo4jRule 4.0 so slow

Tags: neo4j, junit4

To perform some integration tests against a Neo4j 4.0 database, we are using a junit Neo4jRule. This rule is so slow to start/stop compared to version 3.5.

Is there something in configuration to enable/disable to improve the startup time ?